# Give 'image address' of an img in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get image address of an img tag in the javascript

note: I don't want to get src attribute of img tag

In google chrome, if you right-click on an img tag then click on 'Copy image address' chrome will give you address like this

```
'http://127.0.0.1/mycms/images/img.jpg'
```

but if I use this code

```
$('#myImgElement').attr('src');
```

jquery  give me something like this

```
../../images/img.jpg
```

I want give image address like 'Copy image address' of google chrome and thanks for your helps and excuse me if I have grammar problems in my texts

Comment: If you're hosting the image in your project rather than using some web url, then that is your image address.

Comment: @EdwardGuo thanks a lot do you know another way?

Comment: Well if you want the original source you can just use web urls, that would save you the effort of keeping local images.

Comment: Or if all your images are local you can right a function to use the domain and concatenate it to the rest of the address. I think it's something like `window.location.origin`

Comment: @EdwardGuo thanks  I think way 1 is better, please sent your answer into the answer for other people have my problem  in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
console.log($('#test_img')[0].src) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="test_img" src="../../images/img.jpg"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the best way to fix my problem